# Скажите как можно задать вертикальное выравнивание по середине а boostrap 3

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.s-wiev {
  background-color: #ffc45b; }

.view-block1 {
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.view-block__span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #093f92;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.view-block2 {
  text-align: center; }

.view-block__span2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #093f92;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
```

```html
<section class="s-wiev">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block1">
     <span class="view-block__span">
      View All
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block2">
     <img src="img/wiev-img1.png" alt="">
     <span class="view-block__span2">
       Blackjack
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block2">
     <img src="img/wiev-img2.png" alt="">
     <span class="view-block__span2">
        Roulette
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block2">
     <img src="img/wiev-img3.png" alt="">
     <span class="view-block__span2">
       Poker
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block2">
     <img src="img/wiev-img4.png" alt="">
     <span class="view-block__span2">
       Baccarat
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="view-block2">
     <img src="img/wiev-img5.png" alt="">
     <span class="view-block__span2">
       Slot
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: middle;` работает только для клеток таблицы... потому я бы предложил не заморачиваться с отступами и центрированием... и сразу переписать HTML под таблицу:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/rqcedbjg/)

```css
.s-wiev {background: #ffc45b;}
.td {border:1px solid red;}
.vert {vertical-align: middle;}

.font {
  font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; color: #093f92;
  max-width: 100px; text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="s-wiev">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="td vert font">View All</td>
      <td class="td">
        <div class="font">1111</div>
        <div class="font">2222222222</div>
        <div class="font">3333</div>
        <div class="font">4444</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

P.s. bootstrap не знаю, но замечал что зачастую бутстраписты всё оборачивают в теги с классами... везде сто разных ненужных блоков, только запутывают код... и тут тоже не понял, для чего нужно было столько элементов создавать. Текст вообще не обязательно оборачивать везде в span... А если предстоит еще и JavaScript туда добавить, то он работает тем легче, чем меньше элементов добавлено на страницу...

И не уверен, что здесь нужно ограничение по ширине (красные бордеры добавлены для демонстрации)

Если нужно было центрировать список справа - то можно поиграть с шириной столбиков таблицы, в %